# Create md files for site from html: Why does it convert <br/> to \?

Tags: html, maven, markdown, pandoc, maven-site-plugin

I use pandoc to convert old html files to md, which I subsequently use in a Maven site, where they are compiled to html.

The tags `<br/>` in the old html file are converted to `\` in markdown, which becomes `\` in the html file.

Is there any meaning for having separate lines with backslashes in markdown? Does the maven-site-plugin not understand them? Are they some kind of markdown dialect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `br` are converted to an escaped newline, i.e. a backslash followed by a newline. You can tell pandoc to not do that, i.e. disable [that extension](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-escaped_line_breaks):

```
$ pandoc -f html -t markdown-escaped_line_breaks input.html
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Any idea why these escaped newlines are not picked up by the maven-site-plugin?

Comment: unfortunately, there are quite a few markdown dialects.... see http://commonmark.org for the most promising standardisation effort.

Comment: @JFMeier the escaped newline is a Pandoc default behavior. However, as it is non-standard and not supported in most other Markdown implementations, it is best to disable it when outputting Markdown for use by other Markdown implementations.